Installing packages on an EC2 instance in a private subnet
I have an EC2 instance hosting GitLab, which for operational reasons, is in a private subnet, accessible via a Bastion server.
I now need to install GitLab Runner using the Git recommended method  ...
sudo curl -L --output /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64
The above times out, as the EC2 instance can't access port 443 (apparently).
How can I work around this?
Ps - Linux is not my strong point
PPs - I can't host GitLab in a public subnet for security reasons
Thanks in advance.


In a Private Subnet to reach out to the internet you'll need a NAT Instance or cheaper a NAT Gateway.

What many people do instead is bake an AMI with all the tools installed on the base OS image, this way spinning up an EC2 is super fast and everything required is baked in.

Alternatively you might switch to containers and ECS as you can build docker images with all the dependencies easier than building an AMI with a tool like Packer.



Agreed. Just to explain for the OP... A Private Subnet cannot be reached from the Internet. If resources inside a Private Subnet want to access the Internet, they need a way of going via a Public Subnet (that is connected to the Internet). Thus, a NAT Gateway or NAT instance is required. Traffic will go from the EC2 instance in the private subnet to the NAT and then through the Internet Gateway to reach the Internet.
